# Convert AnyObject? to String

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I have a function that returns AnyObject?

```
func aFunction(param:String) -> AnyObject?
```

How do I cast it to a String? and String

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let result = aFunction("test") as? String {
    // Here, `result` is String
    println(result)
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between "as [String]" and "as? String"

Comment: @unj2 "as? String" is an optional String and "as [String]" is an array of Strings.