# Error while retrieving data from parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, fatal-error

Hello I want to get some data from my parse.com class called "Tags" in this class there are two 3 cols "objectID", "username" and "tagtext". I want to read a record finding by ID and afterwords I want to save "useername" and "tagtext" into two strings. I have done it like it is in the parse.com documentation:

```
@IBAction func readAction(sender: UIButton) {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Tags")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("IsRTwW1dHY") {
        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
            println(gameScore)
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }

    let username = gameScore["username"] as! String
    let tagtext = gameScore["tagtext"] as! String

    println(username)
    println(tagtext)   

}
```

I get an error called `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` , please tell me what is wrong in my code.

My class:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
let username = gameScore["username"] as! String
let tagtext = gameScore["tagtext"] as! String
```

`gameScore["username"]` and `gameScore["tagtext"]` can return nil values, and when you say `as! String` you say that it will be a String, and it is nil.

Try something like:

```
let username = gameScore["username"] as? String
let tagtext = gameScore["tagtext"] as? String
```

your error is happening because of that, but your final code should look like this:

```
@IBAction func readAction(sender: UIButton) {

  var query = PFQuery(className:"Tags")
  query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("f3AXazT9JO") {
    (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    let username = gameScore["username"] as? String
    let tagtext = gameScore["tagtext"] as? String

    println(username)
    println(tagtext) 
    if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
       println(gameScore)
    } else {
       println(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Because the `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is async.

Comment: It is correct, and my class is not empty see in updated answer.

Comment: I used your code and I'm getting the following error: `'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'`

Comment: In the lines `let username = gameScore["username"] as String?
     let tagtext = gameScore["tagtext"] as String?`

Comment: updated the answerd, but also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691070/convert-anyobject-to-string

Comment: I think I will open a new question for it because my originally problem is solved now!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read from your response object `gameScore` but it is still `nil` because `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` is an asynchronous method meaning that it will return a result once it is finished. Put the two lines inside the handler and start from there.

Comment: I want only one result, if I copy the two lines inside the handler I'm getting an error called `'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String' `