# Problems with saving data from parse.com in a String

Tags: ios, string, swift, parse-platform

I want to get a record from my parse.com class called "Tags" by ID. I want to retrieve data from the object "username" and "tagtext". Afterwords I want to save "username" to the String "username" and "tagtext" to the String "tagtext". My code looks like this, but I'm getting an error called `'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String'` in the commented section:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Tags")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("IsRTwW1dHY") {
    (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && gameScore != nil {

         let username = gameScore["username"] as! String   // Error here
         let tagtext = gameScore["tagtext"] as! String     // Error here

    } else {

          println(error)

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while retrieving data from parse.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198787/error-while-retrieving-data-from-parse-com)

Comment: Thats a question from me, it's e different problem please don't mark it as a duplicate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift String is not an object. You need to cast NSString instead of String. Once you do you can then assign your NSString to a variable of type String.

**edit following comment**

You can do something like this:

```
if let username = gameScore["username"] as? NSString {
// If we get here, we know "username" exists, and we know that we
// got the type right. 
self.username = username
```

}

Comment: Do you mean something like this?: `let username: String? = gameScore["username"] as! NSString as String`

Comment: Please check edit. I'm on my mobile so can't check the code but it should work.

Comment: If I do it like I wrote, an error called `'NSString?' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'` appears.

Comment: This one was a big issue when version 1.2 came out. Of the top of my head adding a question mark at the end of the second "as" will fix it. Did the code I give you work?

Comment: Yes, I already fixed it but there is still the old error: `'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'NSString'`

Comment: With the code I gave you or the one you wrote and fixed?

Comment: It must work unless parse is already returning a string. Try getting ride the exclamation point in your original code.

Comment: Yes, now it works the issue was that the object already has returned strings. So the solution was to create a new PFObject for the reading part and not using the sam PFObject for reading and writing!

Comment: But the strings ar nil now, but I will open I new question because the problem I've written about is solved now