# Returning nil while getting data from parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, null

I want to retrieve data from my parse class. I want to save them in strings. Here is my code:

```
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Tags")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("IsRTwW1dHY") {
            (gameScore2: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && gameScore2 != nil {

                let username = self.gameScore2["username"] as? String
                let tagtext = self.gameScore2["tagtext"] as? String

                println(username)
                println(tagtext)

                println(gameScore2)

            } else {

                println(error)

            }
    }
```

My problem is now that the string "username" and "tagtext" are nil, but the record is not empty because in the section `println(gameScore2)` I'm getting the stuff back. My console looks like this after this part of code:

[image]

How can I get the data from parse.com in my strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while retrieving data from parse.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198787/error-while-retrieving-data-from-parse-com)

Comment: also this one is not a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you have 2 variables "gameScore2", an instance variable that you are accessing via self.gameScore2, and a parameter gameScore2 that is a parameter to your completion block. (completion closure, to use the Swift term.)

You should avoid using the same variable name at different levels of scope because it causes confusion just like this.

Rename the block parameter something like `tagsResult` and change ALL The code in your block to use that new name instead of self.gameScore2.

Comment: Yes there was a problem with this names, it works now with the name tagResult for all the code in this block.

Comment: Never, ever use the same variable name in both an outer level of scope and an inner level of scope. That is a sure-fire way to create bugs that will drive you crazy. (that path leads to madness!)

Comment: Yes, it was not clear to me that there are two of the same variable names.

Comment: Anytime you write block code that uses variables from the current class's instance variables, it stops you and makes you add an explicit "self" prefix.  That should set off alarm bells in your head. (Don't use self unless you have to. Swift can usually deduce the fact that you're referring to an instance variable from context, and having to make block references to self explicit helps you understand what's going on.

Comment: That's a very useful tipp!